# C# Jacobi Method

Tags: c#, math

I've been working on implementing the Jacobi Method for a C# dll that I will be expanding as I learn more mathematical concepts in school that I can implement in code. I've been testing it with a 3X3 Matrix and a Vector with 3 values.

The input that I have been testing is as follows:

```
double[][] m = new double[3][];
m[0] = new double[3];
m[1] = new double[3];
m[2] = new double[3];

m[0][0] = 10;
m[0][1] = -4;
m[0][2] = -2;

m[1][0] = -4;
m[1][1] = 10;
m[1][2] = -4;

m[2][0] = -6;
m[2][1] = -2;
m[2][2] = 12;

Matrix inputMatrix = new Matrix(m);
Vector inputVector = new Vector(new double[] { 2, 3, 1 });

LinearSolvers.JacobiMethod(inputMatrix, inputVector, 80);
```

The 80 at the end of the function call is the number of iterations.
The function that I have is:

```
    public static Vector JacobiMethod(Matrix inputMatrix, Vector expectedOutcome, int iterations)
    {
        Vector solvedVector = new Vector(new double[] { 0, 0, 0});
        for(int p = 0; p < iterations; p++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputMatrix.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < inputMatrix.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    if (j != i)
                        solvedVector.vectorValues[i] += solvedVector.vectorValues[i] - (inputMatrix._matrix[i][j] * expectedOutcome.vectorValues[j]);
                }
                solvedVector.vectorValues[i] /= inputMatrix._matrix[i][i];
            }
            expectedOutcome = solvedVector;
            Console.WriteLine("Step: " + p + "\n" + expectedOutcome.ToString());
        }
        return solvedVector;
    }
```

I thought that I had implemented the method correctly, but I get wrong output values.

Edit: 1

The expected values according to https://www.easycalculation.com/operations-research/gaussjacobi.php should be:

```
Value of x0 = 0.597
Value of x1 = 0.741
Value of x2 = 0.505
```

The Matrix class:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public double[][] _matrix { get; protected set; }
    public int RowCount { get; private set; }
    public int ColumnCount { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDiagonallyDominant { get; private set; }

    public Matrix() { }

    public Matrix(double[][] matrix)
    {
        _matrix = matrix;
        RowCount = matrix.Length;
        ColumnCount = matrix[0].Length;
        CheckDiagonalDominance();
    }

    private void CheckDiagonalDominance()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the product of two matrices.
    /// </summary>
    public static Matrix MultiplicationWithMatrix(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
    {
        double[][] multipliedMatrix = new double[matrix1.RowCount][];

        //Check the needed requirements for a matrix multiplication.
        if (matrix1.ColumnCount == matrix2.RowCount)
        {
            //Set up the new multiplied matrix.
            for (int i = 0; i < multipliedMatrix.Length; i++)
                multipliedMatrix[i] = new double[matrix2.ColumnCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < matrix2.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < matrix2.ColumnCount-1; k++)
                    {
                        multipliedMatrix[i][j] += matrix1._matrix[i][k] * matrix2._matrix[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new Matrix(multipliedMatrix);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the product of a matrix and a scalar.
    /// </summary>
    public static Matrix MultiplicationWithScalar(Matrix matrix, double scalar)
    {
        //TODO: Multiplication with a scalar.
        return new Matrix(new double[4][]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the product of a matrix and a 3D vector.
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector3D MultiplicationWithVector3D(Matrix matrix, Vector3D vector)
    {
        //Check the needed requirements for a multiplication.
        if(matrix._matrix.Length == 3)
        {
            //Perform the multiplication and return a new 3D vector, since that is the result. 
            return new Vector3D(
                matrix._matrix[0][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[0][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[0][2] * vector.Z,
                matrix._matrix[1][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[1][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[1][2] * vector.Z,
                matrix._matrix[2][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[2][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[2][2] * vector.Z);
        }
        return new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the product of a matrix and a 4D vector.
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector4D MultiplicationWithVector(Matrix matrix, Vector4D vector)
    {
        //Check the needed requirements for a multiplication.
        if (matrix._matrix.Length == 4)
        {
            //Perform the multiplication and return a new 4D vector, since that is the result. 
            return new Vector4D(
                matrix._matrix[0][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[0][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[0][2] * vector.Z,
                matrix._matrix[1][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[1][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[1][2] * vector.Z,
                matrix._matrix[2][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[2][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[2][2] * vector.Z,
                matrix._matrix[3][0] * vector.X + matrix._matrix[3][1] * vector.Y + matrix._matrix[3][2] * vector.Z);
        }
        return new Vector4D(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string matrixAsString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < _matrix.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < _matrix[i].Length; j++)
            {
                matrixAsString += _matrix[i][j] + "\t";
            }
            matrixAsString += "\n";
        }

        return matrixAsString;
    }

}
```

and the Vector class:

```
public class Vector
{
    public double[] vectorValues;

    public Vector(double[] values)
    {
        vectorValues = values;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the dot product of two vectors.
    /// </summary>
    public static double DotProduct(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
    {
        double dotProduct = 0;
        if (vector1.vectorValues.Length == vector2.vectorValues.Length)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < vector1.vectorValues.Length; i++)
            {
                dotProduct += vector1.vectorValues[i] * vector2.vectorValues[i];
            }
        }
        return dotProduct;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the directional vector between two vectors.
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector Subtract(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
    {
        double[] subtractedValues = new double[vector1.vectorValues.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < vector1.vectorValues.Length; i++)
        {
            subtractedValues[i] = vector1.vectorValues[i] - vector2.vectorValues[i];
        }
        return new Vector(subtractedValues);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the sum of two vectors.
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector Add(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
    {
        double[] addedValues = new double[vector1.vectorValues.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < vector1.vectorValues.Length; i++)
        {
            addedValues[i] = vector1.vectorValues[i] + vector2.vectorValues[i];
        }
        return new Vector(addedValues);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the length of a vector.
    /// </summary>
    public static double Magnitude(Vector vector)
    {
        double squaredValues = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vector.vectorValues.Length; i++)
            squaredValues += Math.Pow(vector.vectorValues[i], 2);

        return Math.Sqrt(squaredValues);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the cross product of two vectors.
    /// </summary>
    public static void CrossProduct(Vector2D vector1, Vector2D vector2)
    {
        //TODO: Implement CrossProduct logic
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string vectorAsString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < vectorValues.Length; i++)
            vectorAsString += "|" + vectorValues[i] + "|\n";

        return vectorAsString;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any examples of expected values vs. returned values?

Comment: Can you share Vector and Matrix classes?

Comment: If you use decimal instead of double, do you get different results?

Comment: No. I just tried that. Instead of getting 30000000e+3 I received 30000000000. It just changed the way the number was displayed on the console. None of my values changed. Also the values that I have been getting are way larger than the ones that were calculated on the website I mentioned above. Those values are WAYYY smaller than my values. Example of some of my values: Step: 0
|2.6|
|2|
|2.5|

Step: 1
|3.14|
|4.312|
|4.692|

Step: 2
|5.644|
|8.1168|
|8.5608|

Step: 3
|10.4632|
|15.0416|
|15.823733333333333333333333333|

Comment: You did not ask a question, you just posted a pile of buggy code. Please ask a question! If your question is "where is my bug?", well, today is a good day to learn how to debug your bugs: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JacobiMethod` is incorrect. Here is working one, I have used algorithm from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method).

```
public static Vector JacobiMethod(Matrix inputMatrix, Vector expectedOutcome, int iterations)
{
    Vector solvedVector = new Vector(Enumerable.Repeat(0.0, expectedOutcome.vectorValues.Length).ToArray());
    for(int p = 0; p < iterations; p++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputMatrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            double sigma = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < inputMatrix.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                if (j != i)
                    sigma += inputMatrix._matrix[i][j] * solvedVector.vectorValues[j];
            }
            solvedVector.vectorValues[i] = (expectedOutcome.vectorValues[i] - sigma) / inputMatrix._matrix[i][i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Step #" + p + ": " + String.Join(", ", solvedVector.vectorValues.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
    return solvedVector;
}
```

Also I have modified the method so that `expectedOutcome` won't be change inside of it and `solvedVector` now created from new zero filled array.

Notice that you don't check convergence condition and always do specified number of iterations. For 10 iterations I got the following result

```
Step: 0
|0.2|
|0.38|
|0.246666666666667|

Step: 1
|0.401333333333333|
|0.5592|
|0.3772|

Step: 2
|0.49912|
|0.650528|
|0.441314666666667|

Step: 3
|0.548474133333333|
|0.69591552|
|0.47355632|

Step: 4
|0.573077472|
|0.7186535168|
|0.489647655466667|

Step: 5
|0.585390937813333|
|0.730015437312|
|0.497698041792|

Step: 6
|0.5915457832832|
|0.73569753003008|
|0.501722479979947|

Step: 7
|0.594623508008021|
|0.738538395195187|
|0.503734819869875|

Step: 8
|0.59616232205205|
|0.73995885676877|
|0.504740970487487|

Step: 9
|0.596931736805005|
|0.740669082916997|
|0.505244048888669|
```

Comment: You beat me by 3 minutes. I didn't see that expectedOutcome was being assigned outside the loops...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at [the Wikipedia page for the Jacobi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method). It doesn't look to me like you are implementing the formula, `x^(k+1) = D^(-1) (b - R x^(k))`. What you have seems to be `x^(k+1) = D^(-1) (x^(k) - R b)`, although I can't tell for sure.

My advice at this point is that you give your program variables the same names as the ones in a published formula, so that it's easier to verify that you are implementing the formula correctly. A second idea is to use a numerical package such as [Octave](http://www.octave.org) to carry out a few steps so you can compare the numbers from the C# program to that. In Octave and similar packages you can do matrix operations such as `D^(-1)*(b - R*x)`.